# How can I create a dynamic array based on another array in javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, charts, series

I want to create an array to loop over one of the parameters of the first array (in this example, the desired parameter is the `DT`) and check whether we have data for different applications on those dates. If we have it, it will put its value (in the second array) and if we don't have it, it will put 0.

What I did was also with `const pluck = (arr, key) => arr.map(i => i[key]);`, I obtained the desired field dates (but they had duplicate values). To remove duplicate values I used `dates = [...new Set(dates)];` and finally looped over the final values and wrote a series of codes, but I didn't get what I wanted (Expected Array in below).

```
first_array = [
  {
    DT: "2022-01-01",
    APP: "Application 1",
    SPEED: 1547,
  },
  {
    DT: "2022-01-01",
    APP: "Application 2",
    SPEED: 685,
  },
  {
    DT: "2022-01-02",
    APP: "Application 1",
    SPEED: 500,
  },
  {
    DT: "2022-01-02",
    APP: "Application 2",
    SPEED: 300,
  },
  {
    DT: "2022-01-02",
    APP: "Application 3",
    SPEED: 600,
  },
  {
    DT: "2022-01-03",
    APP: "Application 1",
    SPEED: 1000,
  },
]
```

**Expected Array**:

```
desire_array = [
  {
    Name: "Application1",
    Values: [1547, 500, 1000],
    ValuesWithDate: [{x: '2022-01-01', y: 1547}, {x: '2022-01-02', y: 500}, {x: '2022-01-03', y: 1000}],
  },
  {
    Name: "Application2",
    Values: [685, 300, 0],
    ValuesWithDate: [{x: '2022-01-01', y: 685}, {x: '2022-01-02', y: 300}, {x: '2022-01-03', y: 0}],
  },
  {
    Name: "Application3",
    Values: [0, 600, 0],
    ValuesWithDate: [{x: '2022-01-01', y: 0}, {x: '2022-01-02', y: 600}, {x: '2022-01-03', y: 0}],
  },
]
```

The reason I need to do this is to create a [series](https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/) that I can use to display the chart with ApexCharts.

Real data can also be displayed from [this api](https://node-api.flipsidecrypto.com/api/v2/queries/8809184f-cd9b-4162-b643-d42b6b0aad8e/data/latest) as JSON.

Comment: Your approach to pluck the dates looks fine. Your approach to make them unique looks fine. Then you "wrote code" and "didn't get what I wanted".  That's what needs to be in the question. Please edit to add an MRE.

Comment: @danh I tried to create the expected array in the question but I couldn't and I got very confused. I tied in many ways. What I meant by didn't get what I wanted is that.
Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const first = [{DT: '2022-01-01',APP: 'Application 1',SPEED: 1547,},{DT: '2022-01-01',APP: 'Application 2',SPEED: 685,},{DT: '2022-01-02',APP: 'Application 1',SPEED: 500,},{DT: '2022-01-02',APP: 'Application 2',SPEED: 300,},{DT: '2022-01-02',APP: 'Application 3',SPEED: 600,},{DT: '2022-01-03',APP: 'Application 1',SPEED: 1000,}]

const dates = [...new Set(first.map(({ DT }) => DT))]
const apps = [...new Set(first.map(({ APP }) => APP))]

const result = apps.reduce((acc, app) => {
  const appData = Object.assign(
    {},
    {
      Name: app.replace(/ /, ''),
      Values: [],
      ValuesWithDate: [],
    }
  )

  dates.forEach((date) => {
    const data = first.find(({ DT, APP }) => DT === date && APP === app)
    appData.ValuesWithDate.push({ x: date, y: data ? data.SPEED : 0 })
    appData.Values.push(data ? data.SPEED : 0)
  })

  acc.push(appData)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like this :

```
const convertArray = (arr) => arr.reduce((prev, current) => {
    const existingIndex = prev.findIndex((p) => p.Name === current.APP);
  if (existingIndex > -1) {
    const currentApp = prev[existingIndex];
    currentApp.Values.push(current.SPEED);
    currentApp.ValuesWithDate.push({x: current.DT, y: current.SPEED});
    prev[existingIndex] = currentApp;
  } else {
    prev.push({Name: current.APP, Values: [current.SPEED], ValuesWithDate:[{x: current.DT, y: current.SPEED}]})
  }
    return prev;
}, []);
```

And use it like this :

```
const desire_array = convertArray(first_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const convert = (dates, data) => {
    return Object.values(data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        if (!acc[curr.APP]) {
            acc[curr.APP] = {
                name: curr.APP,
                valuesWithDate: []
            };
        }
        acc[curr.APP].valuesWithDate.push({
            x: curr.DT,
            y: curr.SPEED
        });
        return acc;
    }, {})).map((dataWithoutGaps) => {
        const valuesWithDate = [...new Set(dates)].map(date => {
            const el = dataWithoutGaps.valuesWithDate.find(e => e.x === date);
            return {
                x: date,
                y: el ? el.y : 0
            };
        });
        return {
            ValuesWithDate: valuesWithDate,
            Values: valuesWithDate.map(e => e.y),
            Name: dataWithoutGaps.name
        }
    });
};



console.log(convert(first_array.map(e => e.DT), first_array));
```

Expected:

```
[{"ValuesWithDate":[{"x":"2022-01-01","y":1547},{"x":"2022-01-02","y":500},{"x":"2022-01-03","y":1000}],"Values":[1547,500,1000],"Name":"Application 1"},{"ValuesWithDate":[{"x":"2022-01-01","y":685},{"x":"2022-01-02","y":300},{"x":"2022-01-03","y":0}],"Values":[685,300,0],"Name":"Application 2"},{"ValuesWithDate":[{"x":"2022-01-01","y":0},{"x":"2022-01-02","y":600},{"x":"2022-01-03","y":0}],"Values":[0,600,0],"Name":"Application 3"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result can be achieved by this code.

```
let filtered_app = new Set();
const obj = [];

first_array.forEach(item=>{
  filtered_app.add(item.APP);
});
filtered_app.forEach(app =>{
  first_array.forEach(item =>{
    if(item.APP == app){
      const exists = obj.findIndex(elem => elem.Name == app);
      if(exists != '-1'){
        obj[exists].Values.push(item.SPEED);
        obj[exists].ValuesWithDate.push({x: item.DT, y: item.SPEED});
      }
      else{
        obj.push({Name: app, Values: [item.SPEED], ValuesWithDate: [{x: item.DT, y: item.SPEED}]});
      }
    }
  });
});
console.log(obj);
```

Hope it helps.